# What is the casting in AgensGraph ver 1.3 double quote

Tags: agens-graph

I used agensgraph version 1.3.
Following query

```
'MATCH (a:movie) RETURN a.title
```

gives result:

```
              title
---------------------------------
 "The Matrix"
 "The Matrix Reloaded"
 "The Matrix Revolutions"
 "The Devils Advocate"
 "A Few Good Men"
 "Top Gun"
 "Jerry Maguire"
 "Stand By Me"
```

I don't know why is double quote operator.
What is the way to replace ""?

Comment: What do you mean by "double quote operator"? Why do you want to replace that "operator"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function "btrim" for removing needless quotes.

```
agens=# select btrim( n.value::text, '"' ) from ( match (n) return n.value ) as n;
 btrim 
-------
 test
(1 row)
```

You must use trim on SQL part of quires for removing quotes.