# How to remove needless quotes on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

There is quotes on result of AgensGraph.

I don't want ne

```
agens=# match (n) return n.value;
 value  
--------
 "test"
(1 row)
```

I expect function or procedure for trimming quotes.

Comment: Found a duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54884620/what-is-the-casting-in-agensgraph-ver-1-3-double-quote but unfortunately, even that is unanswered. Maybe you can put a comment there to find out if OP has found some solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can use function "btrim" for removing needless quotes.

```
agens=# select btrim( n.value::text, '"' ) from ( match (n) return n.value ) as n;
 btrim 
-------
 test
(1 row)
```

You must use trim on SQL part of quires for removing quotes.